# App crashes when setting objects to NSMutableDictionary with no crash log

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I try to make a simple score system for my game and I'm using dictionary and save it using  NSUserDefaults to store player's scores. However when I try to set new score to existing key/value the app crash, there isn't any console log message and xcode switches to the unreadable for me assembler code. I know where it crashes because I set exception and it shows on which line it has been called. I also use cocos2d if that change anything.

here's the code:

```
//creates key for the right level     
NSString *currentLevelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level%i",numberOfCurentLevel];


 //checking if dictionary is empty, if empty then it means the game is played for the first time
 NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
//ud is the UserDefaults

 dictionary = [ud objectForKey:@"dictionaryWithScores"];

 if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"Level5"] == nil) {
     //assigning first values for empty dictionary
     dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"ScoreList" ofType:@"plist"]];
     NSLog(@"dictionary was empty");
 }
 //NSLog(@"now dictionary shoud not be empty %@",dictionary);
 //calculating current score for this level
 double currentScore = (numberOfCurentLevel * elementsFound)/9.0;///timeInSeconds;
 double previousScore = [[dictionary objectForKey:currentLevelString]doubleValue];//taking previous score for thi level
 NSLog(@"currentScore: %f \n previousScore: %f",currentScore,previousScore);
 //checking whether current score is greater than the previous one
 if (currentScore > previousScore)
 {
     NSLog(@"dictionary just before the crash: %@",dictionary);
     //if new score is greater then update the dictionary
     NSString *currentScoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentScore];
```

**`//it crashes on this line seObject`**

```
     [dictionary setObject:currentScoreString forKey:currentLevelString];
     [ud setObject:dictionary forKey:@"dictionaryWithScores"];
     [ud synchronize];

//calculating total score (score for each level + next one)
 double overallScore = 0;
 for (int i=1; i <= 101; i++) {
     //adding scores for each level to each other
     overallScore = overallScore + [[dictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level%i",i]]doubleValue];
    // NSLog(@"overal score: %f",overallScore);
 }
```

when I comment the setObject line then everything works fine. Can anyone if there is something that cause the crash? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've answered your question, but beware plist files are not suitable for storing data that changes frequently. They're designed to be read from, not written to. You should really use core data instead of a plist for anything that changes as frequently as this data does. The same goes for NSUserDefaults; it can be changed, but the whole system generally assumes your app will go months at a time without ever changing anything in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
dictionary = [ud objectForKey:@"dictionaryWithScores"];
```

That is returning an *immutable* dictionary, so there is no `setObject:` method. You loaded the plist file into a mutable dictionary, but all dictionaries *inside* that dictionary will still be immutable.

To convert an immutable dictionary to a mutable one, do this:

```
dictionary = [[ud objectForKey:@"dictionaryWithScores"] mutableCopy];
```

You probably also want to save the mutable copy you just made back into the `ud` dictionary:

```
[ud setObject:dictionary forKey:@"dictionaryWithScores"];
```

PS: I'm not sure why you don't see a log message; You should see one.

Comment: That is a great explanation, thank you, and it does solve the problem.

I am aware of Core Data but I have still a lot to learn in the ios programming and it was quite difficult at the beginning. Now I'm watching iOS programming lecturers from Stanford on iTunesU and now I see how rubbish my code is :D. I will use Core Data in my next project for sure. It is strange that there isn't any log message but there's nothing I can do about it. It's my second crash without log error and I still haven't figured it out what's wrong with the first one. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Yep, core data is definitely complicated. But once you've learned how it works, it does not require much code.